# How to generate heap overflow error using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want generate a heap overflow error and slow down the system, however I have created alot of objects on class level, later on creating that class object millions times and passing object into GC.KeepAlvie method using loop. Still I am not able to generate the error or slow down the system

Comment: I have no idea why you'd want to do this (unless it's for some sort of stress test). When you completely run out of memory, you won't just "slow down the system, you'll break it pretty hard. If this is a 64 bit process, you'll need to work _very_ hard to run out of memory. If it's a 32 bit process, your app will get 2 GB of virtual memory and that's much easier to use up. If you hunt around the internet, you may find some stress tools

Comment: The simplest way to get `StackOverflowException` is to create a recursive function without exit condition. That will cause a system crash if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: You can use unsafe code, pointer types, and function pointers. [Unsafe codes in c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code)